# R rep function to index rows

Tags: r

I'm trying to assign a repeating pattern of numbers (i.e. numbers 1:96) to an existing data frame which has approx. 360 rows (not divisible by 96). I kept getting an error where replacement set contains 96 and data contains 360. This is what I had done;

```
stamp$index=rep(1:96)
```

I then changed this to calculate the number of times to repeat 1:96 as follows;

```
stamp$index=rep(1:96,ceiling(nrow(stamp)/96))
```

But now get an error where replacement set contains 384 and data contains 360.
Any ideas on how to get this right?

Comment: You can use the `length.out` i.e. `rep(1:96, length.out = 360)`

Comment: thanks very much, works brilliantly!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to specify the `length.out` in `rep` as the number of rows of the dataset

```
rep(1:96, length.out = nrow(stamp))
```